# Spring rest controller giving unsupported content type

Tags: spring, rest, post

Hello all here is what i have:

StockController.java

```
@RestController
public class StockController {

    @Autowired
    private StockRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "stockmanagement/stock")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addStock(@RequestBody String stock
    ) {

        System.out.println(stock);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

when I make a request like so using chrome advanced rest extension :

Raw Headers

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Raw Payload

```
{"stock": {"productId": 2, "expiryAndQuantity" : {}, "id": 0}}
```

It works fine in that out comes a string of json

However when i try to replace String stock with Stock stock where stock looks like this:

```
public class Stock {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String productId;

    private Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> expiryAndQuantity;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> getExpiryAndQuantity() {
        return expiryAndQuantity;
    }

    public void setExpiryAndQuantity(Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> expiryAndQuantity) {
        this.expiryAndQuantity = expiryAndQuantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                ""
        );

    }
}
```

I get an error where by the following is fed back to me:

```
"status": 415
"error": "Unsupported Media Type"
"exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException"
"message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported"
"path": "/stockmanagement/stock"
```

My question is; how do i create a request which maps to my Stock object.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with **@JsonRootName** annotation, by default Spring serialize using no root name value. like this:

```
{"productId": 2, "expiryAndQuantity" : {}, "id": 0}
```

But if you want that your serialization has a rootname you need to use **@JsonRootName** annotation.

```
@JsonRootName(value = "Stock")
```

And it'll produce something like this

```
{"Stock": {"productId": 2, "expiryAndQuantity" : {}, "id": 0}}
```

You can see more here

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

Comment: Is that not for creating the response json object, the json in the payload is from my request not my response

Comment: But I think it's the same for request.

Answer (score 1):

instead of accepting a `String` Accept a `Stock` object.and accept it from a `post` request than having a `get` request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "stockmanagement/stock",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> addStock(@RequestBody Stock stock){
}
```

and your request should be sent like this

```
{
   "productId": 2
  ,"expiryAndQuantity" : null
  ,"id": 0
}
```

all parameter names should be equal to the objects filed names,since spring has `jackson binders` on class path and object will be created inside the controller method. if you are planning on passing different parameters from the post request you can use

```
@JsonProperty("pid")
private String productId;
```

on the field name.